# Create D3 Tree from JSON using ScalaJS

Tags: scala, d3.js, scala.js

*Please note that this is not a plain JS question. I really need ScalaJS help.*

I have been stuck trying to draw a simple, connected tree graph for several days now. It can be nested arbitrarily deep. I read in this file:

```
{
  "name": "Animal",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Vertebrates",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Mammals"
        },
        {
          "name": "Birds"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Invertebrates"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run this program:

```
package example
import scala.scalajs.js
import org.singlespaced.d3js.{Link, Tree, d3}

@js.native
trait AnimalNode extends js.Object {
  val name: String = js.native
  val children: js.Array[AnimalNode] = js.native
}

object ScalaJSExample extends js.JSApp {
  def main(): Unit =
    d3.json("json-example.json", (error: js.Any, json: js.Any) => {
      val jsonTypedFromFile = json.asInstanceOf[AnimalNode]

      val width = 960.0
      val height = 500.0

      val tree: Tree[AnimalNode] = d3.layout.tree().size((width, height))
      val nodes = tree.nodes(jsonTypedFromFile)
      val links = tree.links(nodes)

      val svg = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width).attr("height", height).append("g")
      val diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal() //Want to draw Diagonals across all links.

      svg.data(links)
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", 5)
        .attr("d", (myJson: Link[AnimalNode], x: Int, y: js.UndefOr[Int]) => {
          ??? // TODO: Draw Diagonal between source & target. Never reached.
        })
      println("Finished drawing paths.")
    })
}
```

I get this error in Firebug:

```
uncaught exception: 
scala.scalajs.runtime.UndefinedBehaviorError:
An undefined behavior was detected: 
    [object Object] is not an instance of org.singlespaced.d3js.Link
```

An alternative signature that I might need to target is:

```
.attr("d", (myJson: Link[Node], x: Int, y: js.UndefOr[Int]) => { ... }
```

My code is a fork of the ScalaJSD3 example app, and is available here: https://github.com/swoogles/scala-js-d3-example-app

It was inspired by the plain Javascript code here: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092

Comment: You've got a lot of code here.  Can you minimize it down to just the bits that are required to cause the error to show up?  That's usually the first step in debugging something mysterious like this...

Comment: @JustinduCoeur I included both attempts because I'm not sure which is closer to the right answer. I'm happy to cut it down, but should I remove the Dynamic option or the AnimalNode option?

Comment: Doesn't necessarily matter -- cut it back *ruthlessly*, until you have only enough to illustrate "I think this ought to work, and it gives an error", with absolutely *no* extra lines.  Cut the data structure to the bare bones, cut it to one pathway, cut, cut, cut.  That's the heart of minimizing an error, and often necessary in order to get anyone's attention.  (And very often, the process of doing so reveals where the problem is.)

Comment: Great advice. I cut it down substantially, but the problem persists.

Comment: I just posted code to github lol with a directed graph example. https://github.com/jshin47/jt

Comment: @BillFrasure however my example is wrapping another js component (native) so I'm not sure it is what you want. I am too interested in doing it without this component, but I was going to table that

Comment: This is getting out of my depth (I don't know much about D3, although I know Scala.js well), so I've posted a pointer to this question from the Gitter group (which is where most folks hang out).  One more question, though: do you know which line the exception is coming from?  I've been assuming it's happening at the `.attr("class", "link")`, but that's not strictly obvious...

Comment: It's failing at the `.attr("d", (myJson: Link[AnimalNode]...` line.

Comment: Well, we're definitely out of my depth, I'm afraid -- all I can tell you is that the error means that your anonymous function isn't actually being called with a `Link`, but with something else.  I don't know enough about D3 to guess at how to debug that, though I'd recommend investigating whether you can access these data in some less-typed way, print them and see what they actually are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scala.js wrapper library is a bit buggy and incomplete, I am afraid. Its failing at `.attr("d", (myJson: Link[Node], x: Int, y: js.UndefOr[Int]) => { ... }` because the runtime types of the links dont actually map to the signatures of the wrapper, as they are created by d3 through the `js.native` function. A `ClassCastException` is then thrown because Scala.js cant cast the plain JS Objects to Links.

You can work around this:

```
val untypedLinks: js.Array[_ <: Any] = animalNodeTree.links(animalNodes)
val animalNodeLinks = untypedLinks.map(link => {
  val linkObj = link.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic]
  SimpleLink(linkObj.source.asInstanceOf[AnimalNode], linkObj.target.asInstanceOf[AnimalNode])
})
```

Another issue with the wrapper is that the projection is only partially implemented, you cant really create an projection for your own Links right now (see the `TODO`s: https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/singlespaced/d3js/svg.scala).

Maybe Lines are good enough for your usecase, I adapted the example from http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html to your example:

```
package example

import bill.d3.TreeData
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic
import org.singlespaced.d3js.{Link, Tree, d3, SimpleLink}
import org.singlespaced.d3js.d3.Primitive
import scala.util.Try
import scala.collection.mutable
import js.JSConverters._

@js.native
trait AnimalNode extends js.Object {
  var id: js.UndefOr[Int] = js.native
  var x: js.UndefOr[Int] = js.native
  var y: js.UndefOr[Int] = js.native
  var depth: Int = js.native
  val parent: String = js.native
  val name: String = js.native
  val children: js.Array[AnimalNode] = js.native
}

object ScalaJSExample extends js.JSApp with TreeData {

  def main(): Unit = {
    println(Try {
      drawTree
    })
  }

  def drawTree = {
    d3.json("json-example.json", (error: js.Any, json: js.Any) => {

      val jsonTypedFromFile = json.asInstanceOf[AnimalNode]

      val width = 960.0
      val height = 650.0
      val marginLeft = 0.0
      val marginTop = 30.0

      val svg = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + marginLeft + "," + marginTop + ")")

      val tupledDimensions = (width, height)

      val animalNodeTree: Tree[AnimalNode] = d3.layout.tree().size(tupledDimensions)
      val animalNodes: js.Array[AnimalNode] = animalNodeTree.nodes(jsonTypedFromFile)
      val untypedLinks: js.Array[_ <: Any] = animalNodeTree.links(animalNodes)

      val animalNodeLinks = untypedLinks.map(link => {
        val linkObj = link.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic]
        SimpleLink(linkObj.source.asInstanceOf[AnimalNode], linkObj.target.asInstanceOf[AnimalNode])
      })

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      animalNodes.foreach((node: AnimalNode) => {
        node.y = node.depth * 180
        println(node.y)
      })

      var nodeCount: Int = 0

      val node: org.singlespaced.d3js.selection.Update[AnimalNode] = svg.selectAll("g.node").data(animalNodes, (node: AnimalNode, index: Int) => {
          nodeCount += 1
          node.id = nodeCount
          node.id.toString
      })

      val nodeEnter: org.singlespaced.d3js.selection.Enter[AnimalNode] = node.enter()

      val nodeWithPosition = nodeEnter.append("g")
       .attr("class", "node")
       .attr("transform", (animalNode: AnimalNode, x: Int, y: js.UndefOr[Int]) => {
         println(animalNode.id)
         "translate(" + animalNode.x + "," + animalNode.y + ")": Primitive
        })

      nodeWithPosition.append("circle")
       .attr("r", 10)
       .style("fill", "#fff")

      nodeWithPosition.append("text")
       .attr("x", 13)
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .attr("text-anchor", "start")
       .text((node: AnimalNode, x: Int, y: js.UndefOr[Int]) => {
          node.name
       })
       .style("fill-opacity", 1)

       val link = svg.selectAll("g.link")
       .data(animalNodeLinks, (link: SimpleLink[AnimalNode], index: Int) => { "" + link.target.id })

      link.enter().insert("line", "g")
       .attr("class", "link")
       .attr("x1", (node: SimpleLink[AnimalNode], x: Int, y: js.UndefOr[Int]) => {
          "" + node.source.x.getOrElse(0.0) : Primitive
        })
       .attr("y1", (node: SimpleLink[AnimalNode], x: Int, y: js.UndefOr[Int]) => {
          "" + node.source.y.getOrElse(0.0) : Primitive
        })
       .attr("x2", (node: SimpleLink[AnimalNode], x: Int, y: js.UndefOr[Int]) => {
          "" + node.target.x.getOrElse(0.0) : Primitive
        })
       .attr("y2", (node: SimpleLink[AnimalNode], x: Int, y: js.UndefOr[Int]) => {
          "" + node.target.y.getOrElse(0.0) : Primitive
        })

      println("Done")
    }
    )
  }


}
```